# Directive to Component Angular 1.5x

Tags: angularjs

I have to spend several directives components. 
But the truth I do not quite ented changes.
It can be done for example with the directive below, in such a case. As?
Thank you very much.

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
.module('01')
.directive('tableSortable', tableSortable);

/** @ngInject */
function tableSortable() {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  transclude: true,
  templateUrl: 'app/components/tabla/tableSortable.html',
  scope: {
    columns: '=',
    data: '=',
    sort: '=',
    click: '&'
  },
  link: function(scope) {
    scope.selectedClass = function(columnName) {
      return columnName == scope.sort.column ? 'sort-' + scope.sort.descending : false;
    };
  }
};
```

}
})();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple explanation about what is component and it's relation with directive was given in the docs.

> In Angular, a Component is a special kind of directive that uses a simpler configuration which is suitable for a component-based application structure, ([AngularJs guide for components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)).

Basically, a component is a simple directive with a default behaviour defined for link and compile phase and also other deep behaviours like `priority` or `restrict` for example. Also, the scope is always isolated on a component, because all the interaction between scopes must be controlled by the component's bindings.

A component is destinated to create reusable interface blocks without focusing much on the elements deep behaviour but on the feature of that block, it's like a more objective directive not behavioral. Anyways, component-like directives have already been used before, but it just wasn't called component yet.

In relation to a directive declaration, a component doesn't change much, it become a little simpler to declare directives like that but it has most of the directives features. Your directive for example, would look like the code bellow.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('01')
    .component('tableSortable', {
      transclude: true,
      templateUrl: 'app/components/tabla/tableSortable.html',
      controller: TableSortableComponentController,
      controllerAs: '$ctrl',
      bindings: {
        // consider using a one-way binding like '>'
        columns: '=',
        data: '=',
        sort: '=',
        click: '&'
      }
    });

  function TableSortableComponentController($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    var $ctrl = this;

    $ctrl.selectedClass = function(columnName) {
      return columnName == $ctrl.sort.column ? 'sort-' + $ctrl.sort.descending : false;
    };
  }    
})();
```

Comment: Not render anything in sight, I have to do something else to make it work. Thank you

Comment: Are you using controllerAs syntax or pure $scope? Also, let me see yor html teplate.

Comment: It was that, and I fixed it. Thank you.